# Mysql trouble using $_SESSION in program

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm trying to use $_SESSION['valid_user'] in a .php script that accesses the table "mail" under "users." $_SESSION['valid_user'] has been defined in a script which I included. Whenever I use "WHERE to=$_SESSION['valid_user']" in my SELECT statement, I get a blank page. However, if I take it out, the script runs and displays *all* messages in the database, not just the message that was defined to show to that particular username. Despite this, I can echo $_SESSION['valid_user'] outside of the while loop or SELECT statement. Here's my code:

`<?php`

`include("mainmenu.php");`

`include("checklogin.php");`

//$_SESSION['valid_user'] defined in checklogin.php

`$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "g00dfor@boy");`
 `if(!$con){`
  `die(mysql_error());`
}

`mysql_select_db("users", $con);`

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE to=$_SESSION['valid_user']");`

//when executed with WHERE to=$_SESSION['valid_user'] it displays blank page.

`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`
  {

`echo "To: " . $row['to'] . "| From: " . $row['from'] . "<br/>";`

`echo "Subject: " . $row['subject'] . "<br/><br/>" . "Message: " . $row['message'];`

`echo "<br/>";`

}

`mysql_close($con);`

?>

Don't say, "Put $_SESSION['valid_user'] in double quotes." I've already tried that.

Comment: Can you fix the code? No need for backticks, just paste it in and click the `{}` code formatting button.

Comment: But one thing that is easy to see is that you have no quotes around `$_SESSION['valid_user']`. Also, you should start showing mySQL errors: `if (!$result) echo mysql_error();`

Comment: Your SQL doesn't look correct. Have you tried `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE to='$_SESSION[valid_user]'");` ?

Comment: I've tried everyones' answers- but no luck. Also, if I add an 'else' statement, the page doesn't display anything

Comment: Got it! I just set $user=$_SESSION['valid_user'] instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE to='".$_SESSION['valid_user']."'");`

Answer (score 2):

You need to put brackets around the SESSION variable in your query.

change

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE to=$_SESSION['valid_user']")
```

to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE to='{$_SESSION['valid_user']}'")
```

---

### EDIT

You need to change

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

to

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

because you are referencing the columns by their names rather than by their index value.

Comment: now the site shows up (the background and menu) but the message doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE to='".$_SESSION['valid_user']."'");
```

or

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE to='$_SESSION[valid_user]'");
```

Both should not be valid queries;

Answer (score 0):

Try capturing your query in a variable and printing it out to see what you get.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mail WHERE to=$_SESSION['valid_user']";
```

If the $_SESSION['valid_user'] contains any spaces you will need to wrap it in some form of single or double quotes other wise MySQL won't know what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `user_name` is a variable, originally provided by a user of your site? In that case you absolutely *must* escape it when embedding it in an SQL query, or you will be prone to injection attacks:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE to='".mysql_escape_string($_SESSION['valid_user'])."'");
```

Comment: the raw data, $usrname, is already escaped and the final product is put into the variable now labeled '$_SESSION['valid_user']

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you escape when creating the query, not at some earlier time.